# how to make it as non closable thickbox when it is clicked outside

Tags: c#, jquery, thickbox

I am using thickbox for getting users information, but while entering when i click outside of the thickbox its getting closed now, i want to be non closeable thickbox when it clicked outside.

How to make it as non closeable i tried with `TB_setCloseOnOverlayClick(false);` but it didn't work. can anyone help me in this regard?

Answer (score 1):

This is what is specified in the ThickBox page...have a try

> Optionally you may add modal=true to
> the query string (e.g.
>
> ## TB_inline?height=155&width=300&inlineId=hiddenModalContent&modal=true)
>
> so that closing a ThickBox will
> require calling the tb_remove()
> function from within the ThickBox. See
> the hidden modal content example,
> where you must click yes or no to
> close the ThickBox.